# Right way to run tasks concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

I am currently facing the following issue with Java concurrency. I want to parse a friend list on a website, then search for the friends of the friends etc. recursively.

Here it is represented visually:

```
         0
        /|\
       0 0 0
      /|\ 
     0 0 0
```

I came up with a solution but it does not perform as well as I expected, I assume my logic might be somewhat faulty.

```
    private ArrayList<String> getUserFriendsProfileURLs(final String uri, final int indexOfDeep, int foldenesLevel)
        throws IOException {
    var usersURIs = getUsers(uri); //long network call

    ArrayList<String> uris = new ArrayList<>();
    uris.addAll(usersURIs);
    if (indexOfDeep != foldenesLevel) {
        List<CompletableFuture<ArrayList<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        usersURIs.forEach(useruri -> {
            CompletableFuture<ArrayList<String>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<>() {
                public ArrayList<String> get() {
                    var friendsOfUser = new ArrayList<String>();
                    try {
                        friendsOfUser = getUserFriendsProfileURLs(useruri, indexOfDeep, 1 + foldenesLevel);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                    return friendsOfUser;
                }
            });
            futures.add(future);
        });

        CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesResult = CompletableFuture
                .allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));

        var res = allFuturesResult.thenApply(v -> futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).toList());
        try {
            uris = (ArrayList<String>) res.get().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return uris;
}
```

I wrote 2nd version of function:

```
    /**
     * getUserFriendsProfileURLs returns list of friends of given steamid DFS
     * algorithm is used
     * 
     */
    private ArrayList<String> getUserFriendsProfileURLs(final int indexOfDeep, int foldenesLevel,
            ArrayList<String> usersURIs) throws IOException {
        

        ArrayList<String> uris = new ArrayList<>();
        uris.addAll(usersURIs);
        if (indexOfDeep != foldenesLevel) {

            List<CompletableFuture<ArrayList<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

            usersURIs.forEach(useruri -> {
                CompletableFuture<ArrayList<String>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<>() {
                    public ArrayList<String> get() {
                        ArrayList<String> ur = null;
                        try {
                            ur = getUsers(useruri); // long network call
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return ur;
                    }
                });
                futures.add(future);
            });

            CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesResult = CompletableFuture
                    .allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));

            var res = allFuturesResult.thenApply(v -> futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).toList());

            try {
                uris = (ArrayList<String>) res.get().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
                uris = getUserFriendsProfileURLs(indexOfDeep, 1 + foldenesLevel, uris);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return uris;
    }
```

Comment: Friend of friend leads back to original?

Comment: No, collection returned from getUsers contains only unique values, 
it filtered out.